# Qt/Qml VirtualKeyboard, switching language by physical keyboard shortcut

Tags: qt, qml, hotkeys, virtual-keyboard, lang

in my application i using QtVirtualKeyboard and i have a problem:
When using the virtual keyboard, I cannot use the system keyboard shortcut to switch layouts.
The application will be used on touch screens and in the desktop version. I know that I can just disable the virtual keyboard for desktop mode, but I would like the virtual keyboard to be available on it too.
Tell me, is this behavior of the application when using a virtual keyboard in conjunction with a physical one - is this the norm? If so, is there a way to painlessly make friends with the system hotkey with changing the layout on the virtual keyboard?

So far, I have been able to implement only one solution - to define a hotkey in QML and, when it is activated, change the layout on the virtual keyboard, but I do not know how to get a list of available layouts in Qt.

Comment: If your keyboard is like mine (which is the default), when you press and hold on the gear icon (should be in the upper right of the ',' key), you should get a pop-up showing a keyboard icon and a globe icon. The globe icon allows you to see (and change to) any of the languages installed.

Comment: Yes, but I need to change the layout using the physical keyboard (default)

Comment: Oh, sorry. For that you need to change the inputMethodHints: on the TextField (or whatever your input object is). https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop

Comment: inputMethodHints only affects character input limits in the input field. I need to change the system language and, accordingly, the layouts on the virtual keyboard using Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift on the physical - these combinations stop working if the application uses a virtual keyboard

Comment: "inputMethodHints only affects character input limits in the input field" -- not true. With the correct flag on the input field, the adjoining InputPanel will assume the desired layout.

Comment: Dear, it looks like you misunderstand me. I'm talking about the fact that I can not change the language layout on the virtual keyboard using the system keyboard shortcut (Alt+Shift or Сtrl+Shift) on the physical keyboard. Moreover, these system keyboard shortcuts do not work at all if the application is launched with an environment variable `qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));`
I can't even intercept this combination to process it for the virtual keyboard as it just stops working